ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi breaks material you dyamic colors
I'm pretty new in Jetpack Compose development and I'm trying to exercise with it. Right now I'm trying to build responsive layout using ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi as explained here.
Everything works fine, sizes classes are correctly computed, but the library seems to break dynamic theme colors, and instead it gives me a blue palette. Not only, it even doesn't take the predefined purpleish colors, just that blue. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it? Or is there another way to do withoyt ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
